# simplexml_load_string doesn't work

Tags: php, xml, xmlhttprequest, xml-serialization

I am working on php platform and using simplexml_load_string to process my xml. but somewhere my xml contains youtube video object like

```
<object width="425" height="355"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/6A1xu0BSs2s&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/6A1xu0BSs2s&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="355"></embed></object>
```

so whenever this object comes in my xml, I got an error. Is there any way to tackle this.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is likely to be the `&` sign in your Youtube URL. In XML it must be escaped as `&amp;`

Comment: Hi James,

I tried it, but its still not working, i also tried htmlspecialchars and urlencode independently and together



Thanks & Regards,
Ashish